# Overriding system vim on Mac

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, macvim

I installed macvim via `brew install macvim --override-system-vim`.  All appears to be well.  When I do an `ls -lart` on `/usr/local/bin` here is what I get for the symlinks relative to `vim`:

```
vimex -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/vimex      
vimdiff -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/vimdiff
vim -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/vim
view -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/view
vi -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/vi
mvimex -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/mvimex
mvimdiff -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/mvimdiff
mvim -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/mvim
mview -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/mview
gvimex -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/gvimex
gvimdiff -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/gvimdiff
gvim -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/gvim
gview -> ../Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/gview
```

Additionally, running `which vim` yields `/usr/local/bin/vim`.  However, when I run `vim` from terminal I get version `7.3` rather than `7.3.754` that I get when I run `/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/bin/vim` directly.  What am I missing here, as it is obviously not the same.

Comment: What does `$ which vim` say?

Comment: Should be `--with-override-system-vim` now.

Comment: I guess `--with-override-system-vi` now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The symlink looks fine. Try to restart your terminal. Could be some caching issue.

Comment: bash was probably hashing (i.e. caching) your old PATH. Restarting the shell fixes it, but if you're ever in that situation again just do `hash -r vim` to clear the cache for vim.

Answer (score 2):

The system vim is in /usr/bin. If your path has /usr/bin before /usr/local/bin, you would get the system vim. Check your path with "echo $PATH" in the terminal.